# Cannot Debug Java code in IntelliJ (using Tomcat) - File system caches were invalidated. Rebuild required

Tags: java, debugging, tomcat, intellij-idea, remote-debugging

I've been successfully debugging my Java code in Intellij using a .bat file with the following code:

```
set JPDA_ADDRESS=8000
set JPDA_TRANSPORT=dt_socket
@rem to start service in debug mode
%CATALINA_HOME%/bin/catalina.bat jpda start
```

I run Tomcat using this code and use the localhost configuration in Intellij which is a Remote config with the Host as localhost and port at 8000. This allowed me to debug line by line, however recently Intellij brings up the following error:

"Error: File system caches were invalidated. Rebuild required."

I've tried the following to attempt to fix this:
Rebuild project, File -> Invalidate Caches + IntelliJ restart, complete PC restart, Tomcat restart. None have worked so far; has anyone else encountered this problem? If so, is there a solution?

Many thanks

Comment: Not sure how the file system caches problem affects debugging, feel free to report a problem at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA with the logs attached.

Comment: I agree. I thought it was strange (and I can't think of any recent change which could have caused this). I'll attach logs to the youtrack link; thanks CrazyCoder.